# Wordpress - Custom Nav menu for logged in users - Shopkeeper theme

Tags: functions

I tried using numerous plugins for this, but unfortunately none of them seem to work with Shopkeeper.

(if menu, nav menu roles, power menu etc.)

I tried doing it on my own and came up on this code:

//

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
  $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
  $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

//

Where my menu for logged in folks is called 'logged-in', and for people not logged in 'logged-out'.

I added this to my functions.php but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already did part of this but i am detailing all steps:

1.- Register 2 nav menus:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
            'logged-in' => __('Logged In Menu', 'yourthemename'),
            'logged-out' => __('Logged Out Menu', 'yourthemename')
        ));
```

2.- Create the menus going to Appearence -> Menus in the back-end, assign each one to his corresponding location.
3.- Where you have the Menu displaying (i guess is in header.php) put this:

```
$theme_location = 'logged-out';//default value

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $theme_location = 'logged-in';//user is logged in change the menu name
}
wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => $theme_location,
        'menu_class' => 'my-menu',
));
```